# UITextField to show UIPickerView in xcode 4.3.2 using textField.inputView

Tags: uitextfield, uipickerview, xcode4.3, inputview

I'm looking to have a UITextField display a UIPickerView when touched. I found quite a few questions on the same topic that say to use UITextField.inputView. However, when I try, nothing changes.

I have a very simple code:

```
setupViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

extern NSString *setupRightChannel;

@interface setupViewController : UIViewController
{
    UITextField* rightChannelField; 
    UIPickerView *channelPicker;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField* rightChannelField;
@property (retain, readwrite) IBOutlet UIPickerView *channelPicker;
```

---

```
setupViewController.m

#import "setupViewController.h"

@Interface setupViewController()

@end

@implementation setupViewController

@synthesize rightChannelField;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization

    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Setup";
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    rightChannelField.inputView = channelPicker;
}

-(IBAction)okClicked:(id)sender
{
    setupRightChannel = rightChannelField.text;
}
```

I feel like I might be missing something fundamental here, but I honestly cannot think of what it is.

Answer (score 1):

```
datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 250, 325, 300)];
datePicker.datePickerMode =UIDatePickerModeDate;

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter =[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy"];

[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(dueDateChanged) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

UIToolbar *pickerToolBar =[[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 320,44)];
pickerToolBar.barStyle =UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
UIBarButtonItem *barButton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *doneButton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done"
                                                              style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self
                                                             action:@selector(closeDueDatePicker:)];
[pickerToolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:barButton, doneButton,nil]];
[self.datePicker addSubview:pickerToolBar];
dueDateTextField.inputView =datePicker; // "This is what changes textfields default responder from keyboard to what ever view you assign it (DatePicker view in this case)."
```

Thanks